# Could a melody played my sportsfans trigger an action over the television?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, behaviour

So I was watching the world cup the other day and some of those fans played instruments like the [Vuvuzela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuvuzela) at the world cup 2010.

**The situation**

What would happen if a company launches an ad with a simple but effective melody before the world cup starts and gets the melody to trigger an action, like feeling the need to drink cola (just an example)?

If fans would be able to play this simple melody in the stadium, could this trigger this certain action?

**The question**

Could this be used for advertising in a real-world scenario?

Are there already any examples using this strategy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about subliminal messages?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: When I read the title I was thinking about voice-activated technology, like that time when adverts for the Xbox One were causing people's Xbox Ones to turn on, because they picked up the voice commands in the ad and treated them as actual voice commands.

Comment: @F1Krazy like that just for humans :P

Comment: Like that but for humans is what we call subliminal message...

Comment: @L.Dutch Or a [Pavlovian response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov#Reflex_system_research) - the question is, how would you train it into people?  Offer free drink samples at a stall playing the music?

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for a Pavlovian response, but without the repetition requirement. However, there are no shortcuts - classical conditioning *requires* both feedback and repetition to establish the pattern of expectation. Yes, it's used for advertising...everywhere, all the time, with minor effect. Most folks are more visual, so brand icons tend to have greater effect than audio jingles. How often has McDonalds or Pepsi or Honda changed it's jingle or catchphrase vs. how often has it changed it's visual branding?

Comment: @user535733 to be fair, the (sorry for how bad this will read) "do di do do dooo... i'm loving it", has been a staple of MacDonalds advertising for a long long time, to the point that most people hear it and at least think, i'm loving it, in there heads, i know i do and so do several of my friends, and that is why you should never have a TV on at a wake.

Comment: @BladeWraith "long, long time" is [15 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Lovin%27_It_(song)). In the 15 years before that, McD changed their jingle [no less than four times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_McDonald%27s_ad_programs). But point was that visual stimuli is generally *easier* for classically conditioning most humans, not that audio stimuli is undesirable.

Comment: @user535733, apologies, i wasn't disagreeing with you, just saying McD has kept theirs a long long time (in marketing terms) and adding a witty remark about something that actually happened at my Uncles Wake, i was somewhat ashamed of myself when that happened...

Comment: If consumers did develop a Pavlovian response to certain tune, then playing this tune on any instrument or through any medium will trigger the response.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like subliminal advertising

The United States does not have a specific federal or state law addressing the use of subliminal messages in advertising. Instead, it is the country's advertising and broadcasting regulatory agencies that deal with the topic and its impact on the public. In contrast, other countries do have specific laws in place concerning subliminal marketing.

Britain and Australia, for example, ban subliminal advertising for any reason. there have been alleged messages hidden in music, for example the rock band Judas Priest were sued after two teenagers listened to a song titled "Better by You, Better than me" which contained a sublimnal mseeage of "Do IT" which althouguh seemed innocent within itself, was argued that the two boys, who were believed to be suicidal already, caused them to take their own lives.

*"The judge, Justice Jerry Carr Whitehead, ruled that the First Amendment's protection of freedom of speech and press does not extend as far as subliminal messages. Since the recipient of a subliminal message is unaware of it, the message can't contribute to dialogue, the pursuit of truth, the marketplace of ideas, or personal autonomy. There is no information exchange when it comes to subliminal messages, and no disagreement or argument is possible if recipients are unaware of the message's presence. Judge Whitehead also explained that people have a right to be free from unwanted speech. Since subliminal material cannot be avoided, it constitutes an invasion of privacy (Vance v. Judas Priest 1989b)."*

*"Justice Whitehead ruled, however, in favor of Judas Priest. His ruling was based on the defense's insistence that the power of such a message to move a person to action has never been proven (for more on this idea, look at the psychology section of this website). He stated his conclusions on the subliminal threat in this way: "The scientific research presented does not establish that subliminal stimuli, even if perceived, may precipitate conduct of this magnitude...The strongest evidence presented at the trial showed no behavioral effects other than anxiety, distress or tension." (Vance v. Judas Priest, 1990)"*

The problem with this sort of advertising is that although there is proof that it *can* have an effect it is not always broadly effective, then there is the the fact that even the best best marketing companies cannot predict mob mentality, the Vuvuzela was not an expected thing at the osuth african world cup and it became huge, but it then went the other way and people heard it so much that they started hating it.

So in conclusion, it is possible that it could work, however if it were broadcast in certain countries it would be illiegal and other countries may not be as effective as they'd hoped. join that with the fact many companies wouldn't want to get caught doing so as it would appear unethical practice, so it is unlikely that it would ever happen

Comment: OP said, in a comment that  predates your answer by  about 15 minutes, that he is not talking about subliminal messages. I guess you were in the process of answering already. Too bad, but it looks like this is not the answer.

Comment: @Mołot, i was indeed. it took a while to word my answer, saw the comment after pressing go, but what he's asking for... is either trigger phrase as suggested by Szczerzo Kly, which as he points out, wouldn't be possible, or subliminal messaging, which although possible is unlikely. not sure what else the OP could mean

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a "Trigger Phrase:" used with Manchurian or Deep Cover agents.

Someone is first taught or hypnotised to perform certain tasks that will become activated with the phrase. (As seen in movies *Manchurian Candidate* and *Telefon*.)

Prior to performing the task the target must be brainwashed or hypnotized to react to the trigger.

In the real world (due to the human brain being susceptible to suggestion) advertisers do play sounds while showing people satisfing their thirst (or just the sound of opening cans) hoping people will go for that soda/beer and not cat food.

Though there have been attempts to use subliminal messages, it turned out that the success rate is lower than just showing regular ads.

My point is, you can't expect a certain sound will result in a predictable action because the human brain works like a sack: you can only take out what you first put inside.

Answer (score -1):

Very deep sounds, like the growl of a tiger, will cause not only humans but any mammal to have feelings of anxiety and fear. This is not a pavlovian response since it does not require prior training - it is just instinct.

So you could have any form of propaganda where you either portray an "enemy" - a nationality, an ethnicity, a polictical view other than your own - and play a very deep sound like the [simulated growl of a T-Rex](https://youtube.com/watch?v=cpipaUfcnmM) as background to instill fear of whatever it is that you don't like. The response people will have to your target AFTER the propaganda has been watched multiple times will be pavlovian.

Or you might instill fear against an undefined enemy in order to sell stuff. For example:

"Your family is always in danger. Protect your family with (company name) ammunition" (with a soft tiger growl as background). People will be afraid, and will go for guns to feel themselves safer from whatever.

Comment: What is your reference for the claim that "very deep sounds will cause not only humans but any mammal to have feelings of anxiety and fear" without prior training?

Comment: @Schmuddi research done by biologists such as [Elizabeth von Muggenthaler](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252156700_Infrasonic_and_low-frequency_vocalizations_from_Siberian_and_Bengal_tigers).

Comment: Re "very deep sounds..." that's simply not true in a general context, e.g. bass notes in music, or loud car/motorcycle exhausts, which (at least for me) arouse feelings of anger rather than fear.  Growls are only effective in a context where I might reasonably expect a bear or mountain lion (there being few tigers hereabouts).

Comment: @Renan: Well, the research that you linked to is the abstract of a conference paper that apparently reported the results of an acoustic analysis of the growl of a tiger. With fundamental frequencies of below 50 Hz, these growls are deep sounds indeed, but there's no mention whatsoever of an instinctive reaction of mammals to this sort of sounds. I've also had a look at the other publications by her (actually, she's a bioacoustician rather than a biologist). I don't think that she's doing the type of research that you ascribe to her. Do you have another reference that is helpful here?

Comment: @Schmuddi [She did test the effect of the growl on tigers themselves](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2000/12/001201152406.htm), and other scientists have experimented such sounds with humans, apes, dogs, birds and other animals. I am looking for more papers to back up what I'm saying.

Comment: @Renan: I'd love to see you coming up with something substantial – the last time I had an admittedly cursory look into infrasound research and the alledged effect on humans I found only inconclusive results.

Comment: @Renan "protect you family with (company Ammo) soft tiger growl)... that is subliminal messaging not infra-sound. maybe at a push using infra-sound to impart the subliminal messaging, and having been on safari before i can tell you that myself and everyone else in the truck heard the Lion's Roar (i admit not a tiger) and all of us jumped up and turned in excitement not fear